# Set Chrome as Default Browser for RSpec/Capybara

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm having some trouble getting Chrome to work with RSpec/Capybara on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit. By default it launches Firefox - we tried to change this a variety of ways, including:

http://actsasblog.ca/2011/09/28/how-to-use-chrome-with-capybara/

`` /home/.../xxx_spec.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `“chromedriver”' for main:Object (NameError) ``

We also tried:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

`` /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:50:in `start': unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError) ``

Is there another step required to use Chrome? I'm new with Selenium.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if I remember correctly:

I downloaded latest `chromedriver` from this resource https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Then insert in `spec_helper.rb`

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

and it worked for me

Comment: We had to remove the gem `chrome-helper`, and manually run `chromedriver` for it to work. It looks like `chrome-helper` was adding its own version to the path. Do you have to run `chromedriver` before your tests, or does selenium start it for you? If we don't, it just says it can't connect on port 9515.

Comment: it seems to me I put downloaded driver to `/usr/bin/google-chrome` and it worked for me automatically (I do not start chromedriver manually)

Comment: I had to go through this again today, only this time on OSX. We could only get it to work using the `chromedriver` from Brew and *not* installing the `chromedriver-helper` gem.

Comment: +1 for removing `chromedriver-helper`. It may have been helpful in the past but currently it is broken due to https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/7. Until the gem is uninstalled, selenium-webdriver is not able to pick up the locally installed `/usr/bin/chromedriver`, leading to the cryptic: "WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515"

Comment: On Windows, I put chromedriver.exe in my home directory `C:\Users\bonh\bin`, and added that directory to my PATH.

Answer (score 20):

Add this gem to `Gemfile` to install and update chromedriver.

```
gem "chromedriver-helper", "1.0.0"
```

See https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper. The bugs listed in comments to previous answers have been fixed.

Then add this to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

Add `gem "chromedriver-helper"` to Gemfile and run `bundle`

Also include this lines of code below into you `spec_helper.rb` outside `Rspec.configure` block.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

Most importantly, do not forget to `require 'capybara'` in the `spec_helper.rb`

This will solve the problem. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
gem "chromedriver-helper", "1.0.0"
```

This has helped me. Try it.