# javascript rspec testing times out

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am using `capybara` and `rspec` to test my rails app. Precisely, I test some javascript code. In fact, running test launches `firefox` (how can I configure this ?). First, the page loading in firefox browser is very long and then I get this error

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
     Net::ReadTimeout:
       Net::ReadTimeout
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firefox browser is starting because Capybara is using default web-driver (`selenium`).
If you would like not to load browser, you can switch capybara `javascript driver` to `webkit` for example. Please, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522756/how-can-i-protect-my-capybara-tests-against-arbitrary-text-changes/22526450#22526450) to understand how to install webkit driver.

With regards to this `Net::ReadTimeout` I think that you need to specify correct host and correct port for Capybara in your spec_helper:

```
spec_helper.rb:
# Capybara.server_port = 3001
Capybara.host = 127.0.0.1 # Try to experiment with this option !

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit # or :selenium
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit # or :selenium
Capybara.run_server = true #Whether start server when testing
# Capybara.default_selector = :css #:xpath #default selector , you can change to :css
Capybara.default_wait_time = 3 #When we testing AJAX, we can set a default wait time
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false #Ignore hidden elements when testing, make helpful when you hide or show elements using javascript
```

If you have problems with `127.0.0.1` address It can be due to the wrong proxy config in your shell. Try to start you webserver on adress `%your_IP_adress%`

It can be helpful to inspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445164/set-chrome-as-default-browser-for-rspec-capybara) topic in order to understand how to set chrome browser instead of firefox if you are using Selenium web-driver

Comment: thank you I am going to check this and come back to you

Comment: indeed I got it work, but it still take 20s to run some simple test, is it normal ? how ca I improve the speed ?

Comment: You can try gems like [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails), [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) or [zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) to decrease this time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out status bar in your browser. Perhaps, the point in a large picture, which demand a lot of time to download to.
Try to remove all the pictures from root_path view.